# Could not open input file: bin/magento

Tags: magento2, installation

I was able to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
 command, but after changing the permissions of the folders this is giving error:

```
There is no directory in bin folder. I have just installed the fresh magento 2.3.

Please help me what I am missing or doing wrong.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the **root folder** of your *Magento project* and run the following commands :

1. `sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. `sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
3. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
4. `sudo php bin/magento cache:clean`
5. `sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated`

**file permission change by ssh and run below command**

> find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 
> find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {}
>   \; 
> sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated

Comment: now my site is showing only text both frontend and backend. I have tried above all commands but not working.

Comment: Showing 404 error on all css files and js files

Comment: update screenshot in question also you can run command in magento directory

Comment: Tried all commands but still showing on text no css,js

Comment: still showing text only

Comment: check my answer now

Comment: Still no effect

Comment: http://m2.gocleaning.nl/ this is my site link

Comment: are you facing problem in cmd?

Comment: commands are running successfully but not effecting the site

Comment: it loading without any styles

Comment: problem in permission css available here :http://m2.gocleaning.nl/pub/static//frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css

Comment: have 777 permissions for pub/static folder

Comment: run this command `sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated` and after any error generate?

Comment: still it is as it is no effect

Comment: I have set the nginx:nginx as user and group is it right?

Comment: INSERT INTO 'core_config_data' ('path', 'value') 
    VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;

Comment: I have run the above query and know site is giving 500  error

Comment: what was the default values?

Comment: default value is 1: http://prntscr.com/mgfa2b

Comment: Still the problem is not solved but thanks Rakesh sir for your precious time.

Comment: Yes the problem is solved now. After executing the query i forget to change the folder permissions. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89270/discussion-on-answer-by-rakesh-donga-could-not-open-input-file-bin-magento).